# is there a way to ignore a scenario within the command java -cp karate.ja:?

Tags: jar, karate

I'm using a .jar, along with docker and a .sh to do the execution.
I use this command in .sh
java -cp karate.jar:./cases com.intuit.karate.Main "$@"

and I would like to use ~@ignore to not run some scenarios, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Karate in version 1.1.0 onwards automatically ignores any scenario tagged as `@ignore`. Please refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#special-tags